# Extend elements beyond viewport edge to avoid hard edges

Tags: html, css

I'd like to extend my elements, like background-colored sections, slightly (or preferably infinitely) over the edge of the viewport. This is to allow a user to scroll over page limits and still maintain the background color rather than showing a hard white edge.

I naïvely thought that setting a negative margin and offsetting back with padding would work. The positioning correctly cancels out, but the edge is still clipped. Additionally, the right and bottom margins behave differently from the left and top, leading to unwanted horizontal scrolling. Here's a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>MWE</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      section {
        margin: -50px;
        padding: 50px;
      }

      .black {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="black">mwe</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems like a beginner question, but I couldn't figure out the correct terminology to search for answers. And when quickly browsing some sites I didn't find this behavior anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can style the color of the background of the `<body>` tag. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/ZERpbOv If you want to style an element inside the body it inevitably has to begin and end somewhere, it's only a part of the document body after all.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Fair enough, but that doesn't work if the colors of sections change. Or with different colored headers/footers. So the body continues beyond the viewport, I wonder why the elements inside of it can't :P

Comment: This is an incorrect "hack". The idiomatic way is to use [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior).

Comment: You can make elements inside the body as big, or bigger than, the viewport, but then they actually will have that size. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @caTS Thank you for the suggestion! That will be my last resort then, but I do like the appearance of the overscroll bounce.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - the closest you can do is set the background color of the `html` element, but for individual sections, I don't think so.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Well, it depends on what you mean by that. I want to increase their size, yes, but not move the viewport or introduce a scrollbar while doing it, hence my negative margin shenanigans.

Comment: You can always hide the scrollbars if they appear, but that will kill scrolling on desktops. Also remember, the dimensions of a viewport can vary widely from one device to another. I guess your question is just a bit to vague to really help you. I have don't good idea which effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I simply want to preserve background colours of elements that reach the sides of the window when "overscrolling" in any direction.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a special device/browser that lets you "overscroll", probably some mobile device? In that case you really have to use the background color of the body or html tag. You can change that color, of course, even as a consequence of scrolling, but I don't think you can have multiple colors.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Alright, major bummer. Thanks for bearing with me though.